# How to check two values in a range together?

Tags: python, range

I would like to check them in one line code. Is it possible? Otherwise, the code I have currently is:

```
while True:
    player_number = int(input('Determine first player Random(0) or AI(1):'))
    player_number2 = int(input('Determine second player Random (0) or AI (1):'))

    if player_number, player_number2 in range(0,2): # shows error
        break
    else:
        print ('Out of range. Please choose a player')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use `and`:

```
if player_number in (0, 1) and player_number2 in (0, 1):
```

You can also use sets but it's a little less clear:

```
if {player_number, player_number2} <= {0, 1}:
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `all` statement:

```
if all(i in range(0, 2) for i in (player_number, player_number2)):
```

The benefit of this method is it is easily extendable to multiple players.

An even better option would be to use dictionaries and compare to a set:

```
while True:
    players = {k: int(input('Determine player {0} Random(0) or AI(1):'.format(k)))\
                  for k in range(0, 2)}
    if set(players.values()) <= {0, 1}:
        break
else:
    print('Out of range. Please choose a player')
```